# how to left align checkbox within an input-group div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am able to left align a checkbox within a form-group.  But I want to prepend some text to the left of the checkbox. So I place the checkbox and the prepend text within an input-group. Once the checkbox is within that input-group div, the checkbox does not left align.

How to left align a checkbox within an input-group div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>bootstrap alignment test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
  .move-left {
    box-shadow: none;
    width: auto;
  }  

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">

  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field3">Field 3:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control move-left" type="checkbox" id="field3">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

          <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Discontinued</span>
              </div>
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-control move-left" > 
            </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the the appended text stays at the left hand side of the checkbox, put the checkbox below the appended text, under the same div with input-group-append. This is the quickest way I can think of to solve your problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>bootstrap alignment test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
    .move-left {
      box-shadow: none;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">

    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field3">Field 3:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control move-left" type="checkbox" id="field3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- appended text is now on the left of the checkbox -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">          
              <span class="input-group-text">Discontinued</span>
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-control move-left">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you insists to place the checkbox outside input-group-prepend div and under input-group div, you may overwrite the flex value of form-control class with the default value of flex, or remove the form-control class from your div and use your own css instead.

```
<style>
  .move-left {
    box-shadow: none;
    width: auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto !important;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto !important;
  }
</style>
```